# How to draw a many edges loop above - tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

im try to draw many edges loop above in the same node, i have writing :

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,automata,shadows,fit,shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt, auto,thick,initial text=,minimum size=0pt]
\node[state, accepting]            (0)                          {0};

 \path[->]      (0)  edge  [loop above]    node      {$a:\varepsilon | 1$}   ();

\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

i want some thing like this (the picture is not pretty  ):

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can adjust the width of the loop drawn by `loop above` using the `every loop` style. With a bit of creativity you can use `\foreach` to draw a bunch of loops. You should wrap those paths in `\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}` to avoid the loops increasing your bounding box size too much due to their support points:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,automata,shadows,fit,shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt, auto,thick,initial text=,minimum size=0pt]
\node[state, accepting]            (0)                          {0};

 \path[->]      (0)  edge  [loop above]    node      {$a:\varepsilon | 1$}   ();
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\foreach \looseness/\label [count=\n] in {10/a,15/b,20/c,27/d,35/e}
\path [->] (0) edge [
    loop above,
    every loop/.append style={
        looseness=\looseness,
        in=60-0.8*\looseness,
        out=120+0.8*\looseness
    }] node {\label} ();
    \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: How to label all edges with this method?

Comment: @WassimSboui: I've edited my answer to show how to use a loop with two variables.

Answer (score 8):

For this purpose you should play with the `min distance` option from `topaths` library and specify manually the starting and ending angle of the arrows with `in=...,out=...`.

In the following example, for demonstration, there are two other paths starting and ending always in the same point, but you could reproduce your image simply changing `in=...,out=...`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,topaths}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt, auto,thick,initial text=,minimum size=0pt]
\node[state, accepting] (0) {0};

\path[->](0)edge[loop above] node {$a$} ();
\path[->,min distance=3cm] (0)edge[in=78,out=102,above] node {$b$}(0);
\path[->,min distance=6cm](0)edge[in=78,out=102,above] node {$c$} (0);
\end{tikzpicture}     

\end{document}
```

Graphical result:

[image]

Comment: To fix with the label size, one should play with the `looseness` and the `in`/`out`, but @Jake answer's does it perfectly and better than I could :).